# Accessing data from a databricks hive metastore

Tags: python, pyspark, hive, databricks, metastore

I am trying to read data into a dataframe on a databricks worspace.

The data sits in a hive metastore of a different databricks workspace  where i have only sql warehouse access.

The datasets are huge over 600 million records in one table.

How do i do this efficiently.

Any other alternate method to do this ?

I have tried.

Connecting through sqlalchemy and also databricks-sql-connector.
Both are working but are very slow to fetch data.